# How do you stop ValidationMessageFor displaying an error message on load?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, view

I have added a validation message "CountryId custom error" to a view. Problem is it displays when I load the view initially as well as on POST.

```
<div class="editor-field">
@Html.DropDownList("CountryId", Model.GetCountries, "Please select", "0")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CountryId, "CountryId custom error")
</div>
```

How can I make it only display on the POST?
If I omit the validation message the view behaves properly showing a default error on POST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This project was created as an empty MVC app and I deleted the site.css and started again.
You can't do this if you want the validation to work as there is vital css in main.css that hides the messages!

Doh!!

Answer (score 2):

Here are the CSS classes used by ValidationMessageFor. It's easy to lose these when copying over CSS from other projects.

```
    .field-validation-error {
        color: red;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .input-validation-error {
        background: pink;
    }

    .validation-summary-valid {
        display: none;
    }

    .field-validation-valid {
        display: none;
    }
```

Comment: I have searched long and hard and your answer actually helped me, so simple yet so hard to troubleshoot. Thank you. Upvoted!